# Void Overload incompatible with glutDisplayFunc

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-c++, glut

Currently, I'm writing a small engine using GLUT. I've been stuck on this one problem that is super frustrating. All of the solutions I've seen online didn't seem to help me out.

I have a function with the glutDisplayFunc in it called:

```
void Window::Initialize(int argc, char ** argv, void* renderFunc)
```

The renderFunc is the parameter I pass into the glutDisplayFunc like so:

```
glutDisplayFunc(renderFunc);
```

Whenever I throw that in though I get this error:

> argument of type "void *" is incompatible with parameter of type "void (*)()"

I'm absolutely clueless how as to solve this.

For whatever reason, you may need extra code to debug this. Here are my Render and Initialize functions I'm dealing with.

```
void Window::Initialize(int argc, char ** argv, void* renderFunc)
{
    Debug debug;
    Window localWindow;
    Core::Shader_Loader shaderLoader;
    program = shaderLoader.CreateProgram("shader.vert", "shader.frag");

    system("title Sandbox");



    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(WindowPosX, WindowPosY);
    glutInitWindowSize(WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
    glutCreateWindow(title);

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glewInit();
    if (glewIsSupported("GL_VERSION_4_3"))
    {
        debug.Message("GLEW Version 4.3");
    }
    else
    {
        debug.Error(101, "GLEW 4.3 is not supported");
    }

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);

    glutDisplayFunc(renderFunc);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

And

```
void Window::RenderScene(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    glUseProgram(program);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: I don't code in c++ in a long while, but your error appears to be telling you that `glutDisplayFunc(renderFunc);` doesn't return anything. So if you are using that as a parameter, it will fail as it is not giving you anything back.

Answer (score 3):

[`glutDisplayFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node46.html) takes a pointer-to-function as its argument.  `void* renderFunc` declares a pointer to data (of unknown type).  These types are incompatible.

You need:

```
void Window::Initialize(int argc, char ** argv, void (*renderFunc)())
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the help! One small issue I ran into, though. In main.cpp, when I call the function   window.Initialize(argc,argv,window.RenderScene); I get another error saying "Non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a ponter to member". I have a feeling it's an easy fix but It's not something I've dealt with before.

Comment: Try `window.Initialize(argc, argv, &Window::RenderScene);` - if `Window::RenderScene` is a `static` member function.

Answer (score 2):

`glutDisplayFunc` expects a pointer to a function that returns void and takes no arguments. What you're passing as parameter is a pointer to void. These are very different things and in fact may even have different size.

The correct type is `void (*)(void)` and to define a variable or parameter symbol with it you write `void (*name)(void)`.

P.S.: I already see the next problem coming: You're probably going to try to pass a member function of your class and you'll get a error of the like "expected void(*)(void) but argument is of type void Window::(*)(void) – type mismatch". A member function has a "hidden" / implicit first parameter `this`. And GLUT doesn't know how to deal with that.